# Transform a data value with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

There's a way to transform a data value into another defined in a regex pattern?

I mean, I want to define a pattern like `a=1|b=2|c=3`.

So when if I pass the `a` value to Regex it returns me `1`. If b returns `2` ... etc.

It's that possible?

Comment: Could you provide a sample source value?

Comment: Why would you want to use a regex for this? It is not what they are made for.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for a simple replace scenario?

Comment: it's not even a replacement -- just KVPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("a=1|b=2|c=3", @"\w?=\d?"))
{
    string[] val = m.Value.Split('=');
    dic.Add(val[0], Int32.Parse(val[1]));
}
```

Or

```
string val = "a";
Int32.Parse(Regex.Match("a=1|b=2|c=3", val + @"=(\d)").Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: @Maximus-Decimus Because the sample input you've provided is delimited key value pairs, this  is a very strong solution. I don't think there's a need for you to do your work with Regexes given how simple and well formatted your input is.

Comment: I think the OP said `a=1|b=2|c=3` is the pattern example, not the string to be parsed. So, like if he passes in `"a"`, it returns `1`.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see you are just parsing for dictionary values/and/or hardcoding a interpolation string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in C# like this:

```
var input = "a,  b,  c";
Dictionary<string, string>  lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"b", "2"},
    {"c", "3"}
};
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[abc]", m => lookup[m.Value] , RegexOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(result); // outputs 1,  2,  3
```

I have used the regular expression `[abc]` which matches either `a`, `b` or `c` then depending on the match, the delegate used inside `Replace()` looks the match inside a dictionary to decide what to replace it with.

Comment: This is good. It only needs the match. Is the dictionary like an hash array?

Comment: @sln Then you would use the alternation. It seems that the OP didn't even want this which surprises me, but it doesn't matter now because the problem was solved. Thank you.

Comment: If you had a hash array, I think a single match with or without alternations would do it. `return hash[match[0].val]` or like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex.Replace with a delegate to evaluate the matches.

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +0: almost nice answer - adding sample code that applies to OP case would make it much better.

Answer (score 0):

The  answer is NO. Regex only return match sucess/fail and that which matches the pattern.

You could however determine a group number match, and that may enable you to translate
that into a value or whatever you want.
But be sure the power of regex is really needed for the job, and not just a simple string compare.
Otherwise you could build a custom trie.

Pseudo code:

```
 pattern = @"
      ( Enie )         # (1)
   |  ( Menie )        # (2)
   |  ( Minie )        # (3)
   |  ( Moe )          # (4)
 ";

 int GetValue( string& str )
 {
   smatch match;
   if ( regex_find ( pattern, str, match, flags.expanded ) )
   {
       if ( match[1].matched )
            return val1;
       if ( match[2].matched )
            return val2;
       if ( match[3].matched )
            return val3;
       if ( match[4].matched )
            return val4;
   }
 }
```